# How to catch changed from data another component in vue.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vue-property-decorator

---

index.vue import A.vue, B.vue

---

and, A.vue import apple.vue

---

and, B.vue import banana.vue

### index.vue

- A.vue -- apple.vue
- B.vue -- banana.vue

If change apple.vue, How to catch in banana.vue???

using vuex, vue-property-decorator, typescript

Comment: Mutating the state with some `actions` and accessing it with `mapState` is a good start IMO.

Comment: So, How to detect in banana.vue???

Comment: As told above: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper

Comment: Using props and event emitting is the key to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a global event bus which can be listened to in any individual complement the usual way with Vue.

Comment: OP is already using Vuex, using an event bus is quite a downgrade tbh.

Comment: It’s just an option which has worked for myself in the past when the method you’ve suggested hasn’t worked or behaved as expected. Mutating the state and using mapState or dedicated computed properties in the desired components is preferable to an event bus, definitely.